# Data attr value showing from console but not by using script

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<div id="result">
    <!-- one of many choices -->
    <div data-votes="9">
        <div class="meter"></div>
        Choice name <span>9 Votes</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to set width of each `.meter` based on number of votes it has:

**jQuery**

```
$('#result').find('>div').each( function () {
    total_votes += $(this).data('votes');
    console.log(total_votes);
    console.log('testlog');
});
```

None of the `console.log` work. And value of `total_votes` stays `0` after this part.

Even `console.log($('#result').find('>div').eq(0).data('votes'));` doesn't work and prints out `null`

But if I use same code in console, it works fine.

```
> $('#result').find('>div').eq(1).data('votes')
15
> typeof $('#result').find('>div').eq(1).data('votes')
"number"
```

Comment: console.log($(this).data('votes')) and check if that is happening in the first place

Comment: You're comparing `.eq(1)` with `.eq(0)`; is that just a copy-paste error?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should write `$("#result").children("div")` instead of `$("#result").find(">div")`. The latter syntax has been deprecated for a while.

Comment: Are you sure the code is executed when the DOM is ready?

Comment: Where do you initialize `total_votes`?

Comment: @Tibos has a good point; The console is most likely executing after DOMs loaded, whereas your code may be executing immediately.

Comment: @BradChristie Yes its a copy-paste error @Tibos The script is loaded just before `</body>` @j08691 I initialize `total_votes` just before the script I provided

Comment: This question has been resolved by the poster, and can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, while there are a few other problems with the code, the issue seems to be a timing issue since it's working in the console.

Make sure that your code executes only when the document is ready:

```
$(function () {
    //your code goes here
});
```

Finally, as already stated in the comments, use `.children("div")` instead of `.find(">div")`. You could also target the children that have this attribute only by using `.children('[data-votes]')`

Comment: But at the bottom of my code, you can see that it says `typeof`is `"number"`, then why do I need to use `parseInt`?

Comment: You don't need to use `parseInt` with `.data()` -- it automatically converts numerical data to number types.

Comment: Right, I never realized that. Pretty handy. I have removed the incorrect statement.

Answer (score 0):

As your code is written, the `total_votes` variable is local to your `.each()` callback, so it's being reset each time the loop begins and forgotten as soon as the loop ends.

You need to initialize `total_votes` before the loop:

```
var total_votes = 0;

$('#result').find('>div').each( function () {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/k46aB/

Comment: I do not see `total_votes` being defined inside of the loop.

Comment: Well he said that `total_votes` stays at 0, so I assume it was initialized already.

Comment: @epascarello It's defined implicitly on first use.

Comment: Yes, it is declared and initialized just before `$('#result').find('>div') ...` Sorry for the confusion

Comment: In that case, please provide a working example of your error at http://jsfiddle.net or somewhere else so we can see *all* the relevant code in order to narrow down the problem. There's nothing wrong with the small samples you've provided so far.

Comment: I was working on Django and I restarted the development server and the script is now working fine, still not sure how that happened, but thanks for the help. :)